# image upload preview: window.URL.createObjectURL() only works once

Tags: reactjs, input, file-upload, createobjecturl

I have an image uploader built from scratch in a React app. The image preview - made thanks to window.URL.createObjectURL() - only works the first time. I thought it was because of memory issue, so I added window.URL.revokeObjectURL() before each image change. It still does not work.

I've heard about MediaSource() api but I havn't found any exemple for images. What is wrong with this code?

```js
export default function ImageUploader({id, onAdd, onRemove}) {
  const [preview, setPreview] = useState(null);

  const onAddImage = (file: File) => {
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(preview);
    setPreview(window.URL.createObjectURL(file));
    onAdd(id, file);
  };
  const onRemoveImage = () => {
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(preview);
    setPreview(null);
    onRemove(id);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {preview ? <Preview src={preview} alt={id} /> : 
       <Icon icon="upload" />
      }
      <input
        type="file"
        accept="image/png, image/jpeg"
        onChange={(e) => onAddImage(e.target.files[0])}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: can you show your preview component?

Comment: It's just an img tag: const Preview = styled.img`
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 8px;
`; The issue doesn't come from here. I've loggued preview, I can see it's not updated anymore after the first upload.

Comment: Go through the code sandbox with minimal code similar to your's which is working fine. [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-wildflower-zclg2?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: I've updated the sandbox with a complete code: https://codesandbox.io/s/red-tree-3kglr?file=/src/App.tsx it doesn't work here, when you drag'n'drop or simply click on "upload" more than once.

Comment: I made few changes.Check your sandbox now. You missed to use the Preview component. [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-hoover-p09er?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: It doesn't work if I drag'n'drop a file => remove it => try to drag'n'drop a file again. Also, Sorry, it seems I've copy/pasted your link instead of the actual complete code: https://codesandbox.io/s/snowy-firefly-zudde

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224280/discussion-between-dark-shadow-and-donedeal0).

Comment: Desmond Hew found the solution, thanks a lot for your time and your help :)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the input value not changing, so it wouldn't trigger the onChange function.
You can use react `useRef` hooks api and assign to the input tag and clear the input value inside the `onRemoveImage` function.